# VK бот не реагирует на сообщения из беседы

Tags: python, вконтакте

Я написал вк-бота, с кодом всё в порядке.
В личные сообщения он отвечает.
А в беседу - нет.
Я дал ему доступ к переписке, пробовал упоминать его, галочка "разрешить добавлять сообщество в беседы" стоит. 
Дело в том, что `longpoll.listen()` игнорирует сообщения из беседы.

```
for event in longpoll.listen():
        print('Event : \nType:' + str(event.type))
```

При написании в ЛС появляется:

```
Event :
Type:VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW
```

При написании в беседе абсолютно ничего.

Что делать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам необходимо использовать модуль vk_api.bot_longpoll

Вот пример работающего бота:

```py
from random import random
from vk_api import VkApi
from vk_api.bot_longpoll import VkBotLongPoll, VkBotEventType


vk_session = VkApi(token="[Ваш токен]")
longpoll = VkBotLongPoll(vk_session, "[id сообщества]")
vk = vk_session.get_api()

for event in longpoll.listen():
    if event.type == VkBotEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.from_chat:
        random_id = round(random() * 10 ** 9)
        chat_id = int(event.chat_id)
        message = "[Ваш ответ]"

        vk.messages.send(
            random_id=random_id,
            chat_id=chat_id,
            message=message,
        )
```

Comment: Сам код работает, но .
При if event.text == '..' он выдаёт ошибку 'VkBotMessageEvent' object has no attribute 'text'.
Что делать?

Comment: @izzytopd Используйте `event.object['text']`